# What is a canonical way to redirect back in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js

I've got action in a controller to go to the another route

```
App.FirstNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    action: function(data){
        this.transitionTo('albums.new');
        }
    });
```

next, I create a new album there (interacting with user) and I want to redirect back to the first url.

```
App.AlbumsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    save: function(data) {
        App.store.commit();
        this.transitionTo('index');
```

Here, I transit to the index page, but I don't want to.
How should I pass data to the albums.new route to get back to the first.new route?

Comment: There should probably be a notion of a "previous route" in Ember. If it doesn't exist I would suggest asking for it by filing an issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues

Comment: Acoording to rickard2 @ emberjs irc: create your own Route which all routes extends from, implement transitionTo() and save which route was last transitioned from

Comment: But window.history.go(-1) worked fine for me.

Comment: @ambivalentno `window.history.go(-1)` would fail if its the first route (on Chrome it navigates to the default page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like the simplest way is

```
 window.history.go(-1)
```

Comment: This works well for me but I'd love to hear from the ember experts about any possible pitfalls with this

Comment: If a user originates from another site on the web this will redirect them away from your site.  This was the behavior when I added this to my login controller and went directly to the route. For that I was able to use the route exception handling via "actions" "error" to get the transaction object and call transaction.retry() to return the user to the originating page as described [here](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589#how-do-i-redirect-to-a-login-form-for-an-authenticated-route-and-retry-the-original-transition-later)